# How can I easily compute the $\log_{60/47}3$?

Tags: logarithms

I'm working on a recurrence problem which needs me to simplify $\log_{60/47}3$?

Since $\frac{60}{47}\approx 1.2765$, how would I know how much of that I need to multiply by itself to get $3$? I have no problem simplifying <del>log of 8 base 3</del> $\log_28$, $\log_39$ or something similar in difficulty, but I'm not sure how to solve this one.

Help!

Comment: How have you calculated $\log_38=?$

Comment: @Gannicus You meant $\log_39$ or $\log_28$? I'll edit that for you since it makes much more sense ... anyway

Comment: If you can calculate $\log_3 8$, would the same methods help you calculate $\log_360$ and $\log_347$?  If so, perhaps you would like to try using $\log_{60/47}3=\dfrac{1}{\log_3(60/47)}=\dfrac{1}{\log_360-\log_3 47}$.

Comment: @Danny: You may be right, but can we let Gannicus answer before changing the content? I am not so sure.

Answer (score 2):

The smart play here is to write this as an algebraic equation.  If $x = \log_\frac{60}{47}3$, then we have
$$
\left(\frac{60}{47}\right)^x=3
$$
Now, choose your favorite logarithm (i.e. choose any base) and apply it to both sides.  Then, use the log rules:
$$
\log\left[\left(\frac{60}{47}\right)^x\right]=\log3\\
x\log\left(\frac{60}{47}\right)=\log3\\
x = \frac{\log 3}{\log\left(\frac{60}{47}\right)}=\frac{\log 3}{\log 60-\log47}
$$
Then, just plug it into a calculator and see what you get.  For example, [google gives you the answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=log%283%29/%28log%2060%20-%20log%2047%29&oq=log%283%29/%28log%2060%20-%20log%2047%29&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0j69i62l3.8394j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) $4.4988$ using logs base $10$.

Comment: If the plan is to plug into a calculator, one needs only the identity $\log_b a=\dfrac{\log a}{\log b}$ in the first place, although I suppose it does no harm to show a way to derive the identity.  But $\log(60/47)$ is easier to enter into my calculator directly than $\log 60-\log 47$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer that's a fair point, I could have left it like that.  Everything having been said though, I'm not really sure what OP is going for, but I gave it a shot.

Comment: It does not matter what base you use, since the answer is the ratio of logs to the same base.

Comment: @martycohen hence the "pick your favorite logarithm"